# Vertical line align property in css

Tags: css, line

I am going to draw a line which starts from left of the page:

I used `<hr>` tag, here is its style:

```
hr {
     background: #D8D8D8; 
     width: 500px;
     height: 1px;
}
```

But the is no `align` property for `<hr>` as describes [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_hr_align.asp)!

With this style, line draws in the middle of the page.

How can i draw line from the left side of the page?

Comment: and the question is...?

Comment: @JozefDúc read last line!

Comment: The page you linked says "*The `align`  attribute of `<hr>` is not supported in HTML5. CSS syntax for IE and Opera: `<hr style="text-align:right">`. CSS syntax for Firefox, Chrome, and Safari: `<hr style="margin-right:0">`. For cross-browser syntax use both.*". Have you tried that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `margin-left: 0;` (Chrome, Safari and Firefox) and `text-align: left;` (IE and Opera) on the `hr` tag.

```css
hr {
  height: 1px;
  margin-left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<p>Example</p>
<hr>
<p>Example</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `table-cell` to let it middle `vertical-align`, as in:

```css
hr {
     background: #D8D8D8; 
     width: 500px;
     height: 1px;
     display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<p>This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</p>

<hr>

<p>This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</p>
```